# Th restriction of a bundle with fiber $F$ is a bundle with fiber $F$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:A\to X$ be a bundle with fiber $F$ and let $\hat A\subset A$. Is it true that $f|^{\hat A}:\hat A\to X$ is a bundle with fiber $F$?

Here we use bundle to mean  a continuous map $p:Y\to X$ with a selected fiber $F$
so that for each $x\in X$, there is an open neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism
$p^{-1}N_x\cong N_x\times F$ such that
$$(p^{-1}N_x\xrightarrow{\cong} N_x\times F\xrightarrow{\pi_1} N_x)=(p^{-1}N_x\xrightarrow{p}N_x).$$

Comment: You must have some restriction on $\hat{A}$ in mind? Otherwise just take $X \times Y \to X$ for example and let $\hat{A}=X \times \{y_0\} \cup \{x_0\} \times Y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of Andres Mejia's comment, a subbundle can usually be constructed *by picking a subset of the base space*.  In this case, given $f:A\to X$, we can find some $U\subseteq X$ and consider the collection of fibers over $U$ as $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq A$.  We can let $\hat{A} = f^{-1}(U)$ and this will be a subbundle of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $\hat{A}\simeq s(X)$ where $s:X\to A$ is some section of the fiber bundle. Then $f|_{\hat{A}}:\hat{A}\to X$ has fiber bundle $F=\{*\}$ (a point).